# Android ListView with Checkbox : Unknown string is displayed

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I would like to develop a `ListView` with `Checkbox`.
However, an unknown character string is displayed.

[image]

What is this string?
Why is this character string displayed?

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lvCB = findViewById(R.id.lvCB);

        List<Object> cbList = new ArrayList<>();
        cbList.add(MainActivity.this);

        ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, cbList);
        lvCB.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lvCB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cb01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
```

Comment: Can share any screenshot for that `String`?

Comment: I noticed. I just try now please wait.

Comment: I was able to attach an image, but how is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> List cbList = new ArrayList<>();
>        cbList.add(MainActivity.this);

What do you want to develop @Wakya?

If you are just trying to create a `CheckBox`, then take a list of `String`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
```

#### If you ask why that unknown String.

That string is **object reference** of your MainActivity.class. That was understood if you make `ArrayList` of instance of MainActivity.class.

Comment: Thank you. It worked as expected.
However, I do not know why `List <String>` is used.
Because I create a list of `Checkbox`, I thought that I should use `List <Object>`.

Comment: `CheckBox` is just a view, it can be any thing, where `List` is data, it can be anything.

Comment: I understand! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding here your activity Context so it's adding your activity context as string in your list

```
cbList.add(MainActivity.this);
```

Just Use

```
 List<String> cbList = new ArrayList<>();
 cbList.add("Add your string or leave blank");
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, 
                R.layout.row, cbList);
 lvCB.setAdapter(adapter);
```